# How to block Facebook friends suggestions?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-privacy

I need to block Facebook friends suggestions. I keep seeing friends suggestions on the main page and on profiles of friends, and I don't want to be shown people I don't know.

Any way to block these friends suggestions?

<sub>Preferably any option within Facebook settings.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

**You can't**, that is how they have designed it.

From Facebook: [I'm seeing people I don't know suggested as People You May Know](https://www.facebook.com/help/336320879782850):

> We constantly update [People You May Know](https://www.facebook.com/help/163810437015615?helpref=faq_content) to provide better suggestions. However, sometimes we might get it wrong and recommend someone who you don't know or don't want to add as a friend.
>
> Most friend suggestions are based on having friends in common. If you see a suggestion with no mutual friends, keep in mind that some people have their friends list set to private. This means that some suggestions who are friends of friends may not show the friends you have in common.

Comment: Thanks! Any way to contact facebook to add toggles in settings for this and also for all similar panels that they have on their network? Simple enable/disable toggle couldn't be difficult or downgrading...